error removing sqlalchemy async scoped sesssion
scopped session is created and works fine; however, when i try to remove it, i get error and the session is not removed from self.session.registry
my extension
class Database:
    def __init__(self, app: Flask = None) -> None:
        if app:
            self.init_app(app)

    def init_app(self, app: Flask) -> None:
        app.extensions['database'] = self
        app.teardown_appcontext(self._teardown_session)

        self._engine = create_async_engine(app.config['DATABASE_URI'])
        self.session = async_scoped_session(async_sessionmaker(self._engine), scopefunc=get_app_ctx_id)
        self.baseModel = Base

    async def _teardown_session(self, exc):
        await self.session.remove()



def get_app_ctx_id() -> int:
    return id(app_ctx._get_current_object())

Error
Debugging middleware caught exception in streamed response at a point where response headers were already sent.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1498, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1489, in wsgi_app
    ctx.pop(error)
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\flask\ctx.py", line 426, in pop
    app_ctx.pop(exc)
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\flask\ctx.py", line 262, in pop
    self.app.do_teardown_appcontext(exc)
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1344, in do_teardown_appcontext
    self.ensure_sync(func)(exc)
  File "F:\Python3.12\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Python3.12\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\zepte\OneDrive\Desktop\Desk\Projects\chatApplication\backend\app\extensions\Database.py", line 28, in _teardown_session
    await self.session.remove()
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\scoping.py", line 217, in remove
    await self.registry().close()
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\session.py", line 1025, in close
    await greenlet_spawn(self.sync_session.close)
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 201, in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.throw(*sys.exc_info())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2507, in close
    self._close_impl(invalidate=False)
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2576, in _close_impl
    transaction.close(invalidate)
  File "<string>", line 2, in close
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state_changes.py", line 139, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1408, in close
    transaction.close()
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2586, in close
    self._do_close()
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2724, in _do_close
    self._close_impl()
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2710, in _close_impl
    self._connection_rollback_impl()
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2702, in _connection_rollback_impl
    self.connection._rollback_impl()
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1129, in _rollback_impl
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(e, None, None, None, None)
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2356, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    raise exc_info[1].with_traceback(exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1127, in _rollback_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_rollback(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 698, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\aiomysql.py", line 201, in rollback
    self.await_(self._connection.rollback())
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 132, in await_only
    return current.parent.switch(awaitable)  # type: ignore[no-any-return,attr-defined] # noqa: E501
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 196, in greenlet_spawn
    value = await result
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\aiomysql\connection.py", line 398, in rollback
    await self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, "ROLLBACK")
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\aiomysql\connection.py", line 724, in _execute_command
    self._write_bytes(prelude + sql[:chunk_size - 1])
  File "C:\Users\zepte\.virtualenvs\backend-imhGe0EL\Lib\site-packages\aiomysql\connection.py", line 669, in _write_bytes
    return self._writer.write(data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Python3.12\Lib\asyncio\streams.py", line 346, in write
    self._transport.write(data)
  File "F:\Python3.12\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 366, in write
    self._loop_writing(data=bytes(data))
  File "F:\Python3.12\Lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 402, in _loop_writing
    self._write_fut = self._loop._proactor.send(self._sock, data)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

if you need more info, please tell.
at the moment i don't know what details i can add because the code that cause of error is seams to be only from extension teardown function.
